# How to use clone() to make parent process and child process run at the same time?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, clone, system-calls

I'm new to linux. I want to make child process and parent process at the same time. But I have failed. Here is my code. Can anybody help me?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define FIBER_STACK 8192

void * stack;
int do_something(){
    int a = 0;
    while (a<10){
        printf("pid : %d, a = %d\n", getpid(), a++);
    }
    exit(1);
}
int main() {
    void * stack;
    stack = malloc(FIBER_STACK);
    if(!stack) {
        printf("The stack failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int a = 0;
    if (c == 0)
        clone(&do_something, (char *)stack + FIBER_STACK, CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK, 0);
    while (a<10){
        printf("pid : %d, a = %d\n", getpid(), a++);
    }

    free(stack);
    exit(1);
}
```

I want them run in the same time, but the parent process wait until child process has finished.

Comment: Please read the man page for `clone`, especially the part about `CLONE_VFORK`.

Comment: @Mat I know. I've try to use execve to make the parent process continue running. But it restart my main and cause infinite loop.

Comment: Here's a tip: stay away from `vfork` and `CLONE_VFORK`, they're weird. Use plain `fork` rather than `clone`. And never discard the return code from fork (or clone, or other system calls), you absolutely need to check it. Also add some form for sleep/wait in your loop, otherwise it will run too fast most of the time for you to see whether it works or not.

Comment: @Mat Actually, to learn how to use clone is my homework. I will try to learn fork too, but I also have to learn to use clone. Can you teach me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`clone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)

> **CLONE_VFORK** (since Linux 2.2)
>                 If CLONE_VFORK is set, the execution of **the calling process is
>                 suspended** until the child releases its virtual memory
>                 resources via a call to execve(2) or _exit(2) (as with
>                 vfork(2)).
>
> If CLONE_VFORK is not set, then both the calling process and
>                 the child are schedulable after the call, and an application
>                 should not rely on execution occurring in any particular
>                 order.

This means with `CLONE_VFORK`, it is supposed to wait until the child finishes or does an `exec`.

Since you run a function in the child, you don't need `exec`. Just leave out the `CLONE_VFORK`

```
clone(&do_something, (char *)stack + FIBER_STACK, CLONE_VM, 0);
```

and both the parent and child will run concurrently.

Comment: I saw that too. But I dont really know how to use execve. Can you give me an example base on my practice? Thanks