# How to test user namespace with clone system call with CLONE_NEWUSER flag

Tags: c, linux, linux-namespaces

Testing the [sample](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Containerization-with-LXC/blob/master/Chapter01/user_namespace.c) from [Containerization with LXC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1785888943) to demonstrate User namespace.

It is supposed to print both outputs from the child process in a new user namespace and outputs from the parent process.

```
# ./user_namespace
UID outside the namespace is 0
GID outside the namespace is 0
UID inside the namespace is 65534
GID inside the namespace is 65534
```

However, it only show parent outputs.

```
UID outside the namespace is 1000
GID outside the namespace is 1000
```

Please help to understand why the child process is not printing.

#### [Code](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Containerization-with-LXC/blob/master/Chapter01/user_namespace.c)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>

static int childFunc(void *arg)
{
    printf("UID inside the namespace is %ld\n", (long)geteuid());
    printf("GID inside the namespace is %ld\n", (long)getegid());
}

static char child_stack[1024*1024];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t child_pid;

    /* child_pid = clone(childFunc, child_stack + (1024*1024), CLONE_NEWUSER, 0);*/

    child_pid = clone(&childFunc, child_stack + (1024*1024), CLONE_NEWUSER, 0);

    printf("UID outside the namespace is %ld\n", (long)geteuid());
    printf("GID outside the namespace is %ld\n", (long)getegid());
    waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

#### Environment

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64

$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
```

#### References

- [How to use clone() to make parent process and child process run at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752264/how-to-use-clone-to-make-parent-process-and-child-process-run-at-the-same-time)
- [man clone](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)

---

#### Update

As per the answer from thejonny, it was to enable user namespace. For RHEL/CentOS 7, [Is it safe to enable user namespaces in CentOS 7.4 and how to do it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1294215/is-it-safe-to-enable-user-namespaces-in-centos-7-4-and-how-to-do-it)

- [User namespaces no longer work in RHEL 7.4](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3188102)

> By default, the new 7.4 kernel restricts the number of user namespaces to 0. To work around this, increase the user namespace limit:
>   echo 15000 > /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unprivileged user namespaces are probably disabled. As you don't check the return value of `clone`, you won't notice. Running through strace on my system prints:

```
.... startup stuff ...
clone(child_stack=0x55b41f2a4070, flags=CLONE_NEWUSER) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
geteuid()                               = 1000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 6), ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55b4200b8000
brk(0x55b4200d9000)                     = 0x55b4200d9000
write(1, "UID outside the namespace is 100"..., 34UID outside the namespace is 1000
) = 34
getegid()                               = 1000
write(1, "GID outside the namespace is 100"..., 34GID outside the namespace is 1000
) = 34
wait4(-1, NULL, 0, NULL)                = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
exit_group(0)   = ?
```

So clone and therefor waitpid fail, there is no child process.

See here to enable user privileges: https://superuser.com/questions/1094597/enable-user-namespaces-in-debian-kernel